# Insert before in jquery

Tags: magento2.2.2, jquery

I have create a ajax call for form submit.

But it returns error .......**h.insertBefore is not a function**

```
define(
        [
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'mage/validation'],
        function ($, Component, validation) {
        'use strict';


    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function ($options) {

            var msgLifetime = 4000;
            var $commentForm = $('#blog-post-comments');



            $commentForm.find('form').submit(function () {
                var $form = $(this);
                if ($form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid')) {
                    $form.find('[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $.ajax({
                        'method': 'post',
                        'url': $form.attr('action'),
                        'dataType': 'json',
                        'data': $form.serialize(),
                        'success': function (res) {
                            if (res.success) {
                                $form.find('[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
                               var h = '<div class="message-success success message"><div>' + res.message + '</div></div>';
                               h.insertBefore($form);
                                $form.hide();
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    h.remove();
                                }, msgLifetime);

                            } 
                        }
                    })
                }
                return false;
            });

          },

    });
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a jQuery specific question and is not related to Magento other than the code is used on a Magento store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your code

```
var h = '<div class="message-success success message"><div>' + res.message + '</div></div>';
$(h).insertBefore($form);
```

Comment: setTimeout(function () { h.remove(); }, msgLifetime); not working

Comment: You need to use it like $(h).remove()

Comment: I have tried this. but not working

Comment: what error it is throwing in console?

Comment: I need to remove message.  still it was showing without  error

Comment: please update your question with updated code

Comment: if (res.success) {
                                $form.find('[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
                                var message = '<div class="message-success success message"><div>' + res.message + '</div></div>';
                                $(message).insertBefore($form);
                                $form.hide();
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    $(message).remove();
                                }, 4000);}

Comment: Please check you have correct number of curly braces in your script.

Comment: I checked it ...its declared correctly

Answer (score 2):

> use $(h).insertBefore($form);

Because now `h` is a string.

you need to call insertBefore with jquery object.